# Expo not listener to navigate specific screen when app was killed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5, expo-notifications

I had a problem when my app was killed (closed) and I received a notification, I clicked on that and wanted to navigate to some specific screen. I am using expo sdk 49 and expo-notification. I read the expo's docs but nothing help me...

When my app run on background or foreground, it's working good. I don't know the reason.
I thought useLastNotificationResponse will help me after I tapped, but it's not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.